# Error on external REST endpoint call using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, azure, resttemplate

My Code breaks when it reaches to this line.

```
String resp = restTemplate.postForObject(URL, json, String.class);
```

On my localhost its working fine but on dev-env server, The error is:

> Error occured in  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.microsoft.applicationinsights.agent.internal.coresync.impl.ImplementationsCoordinator.httpMethodFinished(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IJ)V

The dev-env is Azure Application Service including Java 8 and Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem and solution (For others who will get exact same issue as posted):
Problem: `restTemplate.postForObject()` was failing, there was conflict because 
I was using `setConnectTimeout(10000);` for

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
  return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
}
private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory(){
  HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory .......
  factory.setConnectTime(...);
  return factory
}
```

The problem was solved when I removed `clientHttpRequestFactory()` from restTemplate and configured default without the connect timeout. Now it's not conflicting.

@Gaurav I will mark your answer because your response gave me an idea about the dependency conflict issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be like a library issue: somehow your environment has two incompatible versions of the same library.
Just run

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

or remove manually the invalid jar.

Comment: Exception means method name "httpMethodFinished"  with arguments of type (String,...) not found so either you miss the jar which contains class "com.microsoft.applicationinsights.agent.internal.coresync.impl.ImplementationsCoordinator" not there or two incompatible versions of the same library is present there.

Comment: Ah make sense, I will try to check azure application insight for my java app and its dependency

Comment: Thanks and the problem has been resolved. I have marked your answer because your answer gave hints about dependency issue as well as I have posted where was the issue exactly.